# Android studio comment posting page not working

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a comment page like Instagram in the project I have done on Android studio. The comment fragment is coming, but when I write the comment and send it, it stops.Comments section does not occur in the firebase.I want to post comments on my project and then see those comments.The run part expresses like this. I have searched but could not find

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geziproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject">
        <activity android:name=".AnasayfaActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".bos" />
        <activity android:name=".kayitol" />
        <activity android:name=".kullanicigiris" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat:**

```
Run:

Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@1581393
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1870)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1847)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:755)
        at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):1)
        at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):2)
        at lv.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):9)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):3)
        at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):3)
```

**fragment_yorumyaz.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Yorumyaz1Fragment">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_yorumlar">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_yorumlar"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_yorumlar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_relative">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_relative"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/profilresmi_yorumlar"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        </com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Yorumunuzu giriniz"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/edit_yorumlar"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gonder"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profilresmi_yorumlar"
            >
        </EditText>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Gönder"
            android:id="@+id/gonder"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Yorumyaz1Fragment.java:**

```
public class Yorumyaz1Fragment extends Fragment {
    EditText edit_yorumlar;
    ImageView profilresmi_yorumlar;
    TextView gonder;
    String gonderi_id;
    String gonderen_id;
    FirebaseUser mevcutkullanici;
    private Intent intent;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference reference;


    public void YorumlarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yorumyaz, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootview.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yorumlar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Yorumlar");
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> getActivity().finish());
        edit_yorumlar = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.edit_yorumlar);
        profilresmi_yorumlar = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.profilresmi_yorumlar);
        gonder = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.gonder);
 mevcutkullanici= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        
        Intent intent= new Intent();
        gonderi_id=intent.getStringExtra("gonderi_id");
        gonderen_id=intent.getStringExtra("gonderen_id");

        gonder.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (edit_yorumlar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Boş yorum gönderemezsiniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                yorumEkle();
            }

        });


        return rootview;
    }

    private void yorumEkle() {
        DatabaseReference yorumlarYolu = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("yorumlar").child(gonderi_id);
     

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("yorum", edit_yorumlar.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("gonderen", mevcutkullanici.getUid());
        yorumlarYolu.push().setValue(hashMap);
        edit_yorumlar.setText("");
       
 }
```

Comment: The logcat says "Service not registered". This is usually thrown when the service which you are trying to start hasn't been declared in the Manifest. Are you sure that the code snippets which you posted above is correct? Also, do you have a Git Link for your project, helping us to check the files/codes in more detail?

Comment: I added AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: https://github.com/kubraokur/geziproject

Comment: I did the codes by looking at the video, it works on the video.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, you didn't declare your service in your Manifest - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

Comment: I didn't know how to name the service because the page I am using is a fragment. Can you help me?